# Possible migration from Programmers

Tags: discussion, migration

Do you guys want [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113526/test-a-cluster-of-cpus) on testing a cluster of CPUs.

It's already got one plain close vote and a flag for migration here.

Comment: Thanks for asking.  God, I wish less crap would fly around in the migration tubes...  It was a valiant effort.  http://serverfault.com/questions/320285/how-can-i-test-a-cluster-of-cpus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mm, that's a dirty question. That'll require a fair amount of back-n-forth to really get the right details.

Comment: OK - I'll just close as off topic and say he should repost with a **lot** more information.

Comment: Just to re-inforce, we'd probably end up closing it here as NARQ

Comment: ...and, he [re-posted verbatim](http://serverfault.com/questions/320285/how-can-i-test-a-cluster-of-cpus).

Answer (score 5):

No, absolutely not. That's such a poor question it needs to be closed, not migrated. Unless it's really obvious that a question really is about an administration issue AND appears to have sufficient information to make it answerable please don't send it to SF. I don't think I'm the only tired of closing crap that has been migrated over.

Comment: My first thought was to simply close it, but there was a comment and a flag so I decided to double check.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/320285/how-can-i-test-a-cluster-of-cpus

Comment: That link pretty much says it all.